# Organizar datos después de $.ajax bloquea navegador

Tags: jquery, ajax

Intentando reorganizar una tabla que pinto con resultados `$.ajax` no se por qué pero en local funciona, pero al ponerlo en el servidor el código me deja bloqueado la pestaña.

Los datos de `$.ajax` me llegan correctos pero al hacer esto después de pintar mi HTML con los datos, falla

```
 var listaNIF=[];
    $("#ajax_socios tbody [data-multi != 'false']").each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr("data-multi")==undefined)
          return ;
        var nif=$(this).attr("data-multi");
        if (listaNIF.indexOf(nif)==-1)
          listaNIF.push(nif);
        var contArray = 0;
        // Proceso 1 
        listaNIF.forEach(function(item){
            // empezamos a buscar elementos
            $("#ajax_socios tbody tr[data-multi="+item+"][data-nif!="+item+"]").each(function(){
              var componente = $(this);
              var plantilla = "<tr class='filamulti'><td>&nbsp;</td><td data-socio="+$(componente).attr("data-socio")+" data-nif="+item+" colspan='6'>"+$(componente).attr("data-socio")+" - "+ $(componente).attr("data-nombre")+" - "+$(componente).attr("data-nif")+"&nbsp;&nbsp;<img class='quitaCuenta' src='imagenes/userminus.png' /></td></tr>";
              $("#ajax_socios tbody tr[data-multi="+item+"][data-nif="+item+"]").after(plantilla);
              $(this).remove();
            });
        });// end forEach
        // Proceso 2
        listaNIF.forEach(function(item){
          var elementoFirst = $("#ajax_socios tbody tr[data-multi="+item+"][data-nif="+item+"]:first");
          $("#ajax_socios tbody tr[data-multi="+item+"]").each(function(){
            var componente = $(this);
              if ($(componente).attr("data-socio")!==$(elementoFirst).attr("data-socio")){
                var plantilla = "<tr class='filamulti'><td>&nbsp;</td><td data-socio="+$(componente).attr("data-socio")+" data-nif="+item+" colspan='6'>"+$(componente).attr("data-socio")+" - "+ $(componente).attr("data-nombre")+" - "+$(componente).attr("data-nif")+"&nbsp;&nbsp;<img class='quitaCuenta' src='imagenes/userminus.png' /></td></tr>";
                $(elementoFirst).after(plantilla);
                $(this).remove();
              }
          });
        });
    });// end .each principal
```

No entiendo si es la forma de realizar el proceso o qué.

Comment: Hola, puedes mostrar el error en consola o una imagen del error que se muestre?

Comment: Hola @AlbertArias la cosa está en que no muestra error, sino que se queda bloqueado al subirlo. Las pruebas en local me funcionan perfectas, y la consola arroja 0 errores, pero al subirlo deja bloqueada la pestaña incluso

Comment: Con respecto a "bloqueada la pestaña", tenés la opción `async: false` en la función $.ajax()? Porque ese podría ser el problema. Si es así, entonces comentá todo y fijate de hacer un console.log() de la respuesta de la función de AJAX, quizás el server no está devolviendo nada y como es sincrónica todo se bloquea

Comment: Sí, en la llamada está puesto...¿podría ser por el volumen de datos? serían unos 4000 registros. He intentado poner el código de más arriba en el `complete` del $.ajax pero tampoco, se queda igual @Genarito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno, ya he encontrado el problema.

No me había dado cuenta del detalle siguiente: había metido el proceso del `forEach` de mi array **dentro del .each de jQuery** cuando debía estar fuera. Se ve que ahí se hacía un lío, ha sido sacarlo fuera del bucle y ya funciona correctamente.

El código quedaría:

```
var listaNIF=[];
    $("#ajax_socios tbody [data-multi != 'false']").each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr("data-multi")==undefined)
          return ;
        var nif=$(this).attr("data-multi");
        if (listaNIF.indexOf(nif)==-1)
          listaNIF.push(nif);
    });// end .each principal
// Proceso 1 
            listaNIF.forEach(function(item){
                // empezamos a buscar elementos
                $("#ajax_socios tbody tr[data-multi="+item+"][data-nif!="+item+"]").each(function(){
                  var componente = $(this);
                  var plantilla = "<tr class='filamulti'><td>&nbsp;</td><td data-socio="+$(componente).attr("data-socio")+" data-nif="+item+" colspan='6'>"+$(componente).attr("data-socio")+" - "+ $(componente).attr("data-nombre")+" - "+$(componente).attr("data-nif")+"&nbsp;&nbsp;<img class='quitaCuenta' src='imagenes/userminus.png' /></td></tr>";
                  $("#ajax_socios tbody tr[data-multi="+item+"][data-nif="+item+"]").after(plantilla);
                  $(this).remove();
                });
            });// end forEach
            // Proceso 2
            listaNIF.forEach(function(item){
              var elementoFirst = $("#ajax_socios tbody tr[data-multi="+item+"][data-nif="+item+"]:first");
              $("#ajax_socios tbody tr[data-multi="+item+"]").each(function(){
                var componente = $(this);
                  if ($(componente).attr("data-socio")!==$(elementoFirst).attr("data-socio")){
                    var plantilla = "<tr class='filamulti'><td>&nbsp;</td><td data-socio="+$(componente).attr("data-socio")+" data-nif="+item+" colspan='6'>"+$(componente).attr("data-socio")+" - "+ $(componente).attr("data-nombre")+" - "+$(componente).attr("data-nif")+"&nbsp;&nbsp;<img class='quitaCuenta' src='imagenes/userminus.png' /></td></tr>";
                    $(elementoFirst).after(plantilla);
                    $(this).remove();
                  }
              });
            });
```

Gracias!

Comment: Te recomiendo refactorizar tu código un poco. En el estado actual es difícil leer y en un futuro será más difícil de mantener. Estructura tu código en funciones, módulos, para que tengas todo ordenado. Plantéate también en un futuro, para cosas más grandes, utilizar un framework frontend. Saludos.

Comment: Si @guzgarcia lo tengo dividido por funciones, sólo he puesto el código que me estaba dando problemas porque estaba ya probando y probando a ver qué podía ser. ;)

Comment: Debieras marcar como aceptada tu propia respuesta. :)